# Photos framework ascending in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, photosframework

I have a collectionView running in my project that fetches iPhone photo library by using Photos framework successfully.I am trying to ascending the photo collectionView from last photo.I am using the following code....

```
  func getAllPhotosInfo() {
   photoAssets = []

    let options = PHFetchOptions()
    options.sortDescriptors = [
        NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate", ascending: false)
    ]

    let assets: PHFetchResult = PHAsset.fetchAssetsWithMediaType(.Image, options: options)
    assets.enumerateObjectsUsingBlock { (asset, index, stop) -> Void in
        self.photoAssets.append(asset as! PHAsset)
    }
    print(photoAssets)
}
```

//PHAsset to image conversion

```
import UIKit
import Photos

class CollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

var imageManager: PHImageManager?

@IBOutlet weak var photoImageView: UIImageView!

var imageAsset: PHAsset? {
    didSet {

            self.imageManager?.requestImageForAsset(self.imageAsset!, targetSize: CGSize(width: 320, height: 320), contentMode: .AspectFill, options: nil) { image, info in
            self.photoImageView.image = image
        }

    }
}
```

}

Comment: So far so good... what seems to be the problem?

Comment: @luk2302 I am running the getAllPhotosInfo() function inside the ViewDidLoad but it not ascending the collection view...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was playing with the Photos framework doc and I found the answer.here is the working code....

```
var photoAssets = [PHAsset]()

func getAllPhotosInfo() {
   photoAssets = []

   let options = PHFetchOptions()
   options.sortDescriptors = [ NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate", ascending: false) ]
   options.predicate =  NSPredicate(format: "mediaType = %i", PHAssetMediaType.Image.rawValue)
   let assetCollections = PHAssetCollection.fetchAssetCollectionsWithType(PHAssetCollectionType.SmartAlbum, subtype: PHAssetCollectionSubtype.SmartAlbumUserLibrary, options: nil)

for i in 0 ..< assetCollections.count
{

        if let assetCollection = assetCollections[i] as? PHAssetCollection
        {
           images = PHAsset.fetchAssetsInAssetCollection(assetCollection, options: options)

             print(images.count)

            return
        }
   }
}
```